# How to prefetch multiple fields by the same queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to do a Prefetch on my Models

The Models are like so:

```
Model A
     ---Field 1
     ---Field 2

Model B
     ---Field RR FK to Model A related_name RR
     ---Field SS FK to Model A related_name SS
```

I was making a prefetch for my model A and I ended up with something like this

```
   B = B.objects.all()
   A = A.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch('RR', queryset=B),
            Prefetch('SS', queryset=B)
      )
```

However, this results in 2 queries (one for RR, and one for SS) to the same queryset.

Is there any way to avoid this by making RR and SS use the same prefetch?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing.. did you get it to work somehow?

Comment: No I had to redesign the data structure to avoid it